# Copy data from multiple tables in one database to another

Tags: mysql-workbench

I need to copy data from multiple tables (100+) in DB1 to the corresponding tables in DB2 (while keeping the existing data in DB2 intact).

Tables in DB2 may have existing primary key values same as DB1, so while writing data into DB2 new primary key values need to be generated and used wherever they are referenced as foreign keys.

Both DB1 and DB2 are MySQL databases and have the same schema.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first do not use MySQL Workbench (as your tag seems to suggest), it is not its purpose.

I would use an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) (Extract, Transform, Load) like [Pentaho Data Integration](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/) or [Talend](http://www.talend.com/) (both free) to do the job.